# Entity Framework / POCO/ WCF

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

We are creating a website from scratch and the will be created in MVC 4.0 With EF4.0
And we wish to create a common data access layer using EF and expose the EF using WCF. As the EF contains the CodeLogic we wish to separate the EF from the client calls. The client has to call the WCF via POCO object and the WCF will inturn return some kind of results using POCO.

And my question is this kind of logic is ok. How can I convert POCO to EF and vice versa.

Thanks for your time and patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if it is a good idea to expose Entities directly from a webservice. Maybe you wanna use a [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and maybe you wanna use a WCF REST or a WebApi (webservice is quite outdated). That would be a good idea if you have your Business logic inside the WebService. If not, it's quite weird to use Entify Framework capabilities and then hide all the advantages behind a webservice.

Anyway, there is a awesome tool for converting from one object to another, it's called [automapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Could I use the DTO/POCO object as the arguments for the WCF Services and then WCF Service Call does the manipulation of the EF?

Comment: one valid strategy is: call the service. The service does all the business logic with EF & database, and gets the desired result. Then, you use automapper to transform the result to Data Transfer Objects and returns it to the client. One huge advantage is that you don't couple the service clients to your Entity details. You can change the Entities without change the DTO and of course, you can hide inconvenient information to the client (internal IDs, ...)

Comment: This looks good for. One final question. Will this WCF/EF will lead to any of security hole?

Comment: WCF have lot's of security options. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx.